# rails/ruby: filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 query = Micropost.order("created_at desc")
  unless params[:tag_id].blank? or params[:tag_id] == "Select a tag"
    tags = Tag.all
    params[:tag_id].each do |index|
      query = tags[Integer(index) - 1].microposts.order("created_at desc") & query
    end
  end
```

This is the code I have. Basically tags have microposts and when I specify an array of tags from params[:tag_id] (I use a multiple select_tag), I want the intersection of all those microposts specified by the tags.

This code works when the array has only one tag but doesnt seem to work with more than 1. Wheres the bug?

Comment: I get  "tag_id"=>["64", "6"] for tag_id, is split necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are trying to do. But perhaps something along these lines is what you are after (goes inside the `unless`)?

For posts that have any tag:

```
tags = Tags.where(:id => params[:tag_id]).all
posts_with_tags = tags.map(&:microposts).flatten.uniq
```

For posts that have all tags:

```
tags = Tags.where(:id => params[:tag_id]).all
posts_with_tags = tags.map(&:microposts).inject { |memo, elem| memo & elem }
```

Comment: this works in giving a or b. How can you modify to give a and b? where a and b are tags.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the intersection of all Micropost with the collection of microposts associated with the tags selected you have only to query for all the micropost associated with the selected Tag and collect the microposts.
with rails3

```
  unless params[:tag_id].blank? or params[:tag_id] == "Select a tag"
   query= Tag.where(["id in (?)",params[:tag_id]]).collect(&:microposts).uniq
end
```

maybe i have misunderstood your question , sorry .

Comment: Not sure, you might be missing a `flatten`

Comment: I got undefined method for all